# Cannot span a window across monitors when changed to portrait orientation

Tags: multiple-monitors

My previous setup was with 3 monitors in landscape 1280x1024. With that I was able to full screen a window over the  3 monitors and to move windows freely between screens.

I've changed my screens to portrait orientation and now I cannot expand a window beyond the size of one screen, nor move windows from one screen to the other.

Gtx970, gnome session fallback. 14.04 32 bit.

Answer (score 0):

When rotating the screens the NVIDIA driver does not know that it has to stitch the 3 screens together. You will see a small black space when opening the display manager. Just resize, move so the 3 monitors are really side by side. I did not saw that because I ve changed screen orientation in Preferences and not within the NVIDIA interface.